# Partial differential question

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $z=z(x,y)$ be $C^1(R^2,R)$ and non-zero and $f$ another $C^1(R^2,R)$ function such that for all $x,y\in R$
$$f(yz,xz)=0.$$
Prove that $f_x z_x=f_y z_y$. I've tried this by differentiating with respect to $x$ and $y$ and setting it equal to $0$ but I seem to get nowhere near the answer.

Comment: What is $g$? There is not in first equation.

Comment: Ohh i meant $z$

Answer (score 0):

I think there's actually a mistake in the question. Consider $z=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}$ which is a non-zero $C^1$ function. Then for all $x,y\in R$, $||(yz,xz)||=\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{1+x^2+y^2}+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2+y^2}}<1$. That is, the equation
$$f(yz,xz)=0$$ describes what happens in the unit disk. There's no way to know what happens outside of said disk and it's easy to construct a function that behaves in a way that contradicts the equality $f_xg_x=f_yg_y$.